# How to using ireport in jsp

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ireport

how to using Ireport jasper in jsp 
please help me to solve it...
can you give me like source code in jsp 
to call IReport?

Comment: [Check This out for Reference](http://forums.codecharge.com/posts.php?post_id=53893)

Answer (score 0):

I think the question should be how to use jasperreport in jsp. Ireport is just a tool for you to design how the report should look like(type, look and feel, etc).
Now to use jasperreport you need either a yourireportfile.jxml or yourireportfile.jasper, jasperreport jar, a datasource to pass to the report.the rest can be easily found on google or in the jasperreport documentation.

I hope this would point you to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

- Create a servlet that outputs a pdf file by changing the content type `response.setContentType( "application/pdf" );`
- Use `JRPdfExporter` to output a pdf file.

  - Connect the servlet output stream to the `pdfExporter` by calling `setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream())`